# Как вызвать хранимую процедуру в Asp net core 3.0 (Update/Insert)

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

У меня есть хранимая процедура

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddReserv
    @Place int,
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
        
    insert into [dbo].Reserv(UserId, Place,  StartDate, EndDate)
    values(1, @Place, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    
END
```

Я из контроллера по методу `post` хочу добавить новую запись в таблице. Не могу понять как передать параметры в хранимку.

```
// POST: api/CreateReserv
            [HttpPost]
            public void Post(string value)
            {
                using (var connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.CommandText = "AddReserv";
                        //Добавить параметры
                        /*
                        @Place int
                        @StartDate datetime
                        @EndDate datetime
                         */
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       
    
    
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```
        public void Post(string value)
        {
            using (var connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "AddReserv";

                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Place", place));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("StartDate", startDate));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EndDate", endDate));
                    
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
        }
```

единственно определите сами параметры верно.

Comment: Я не вижу функции `AddWithValue` у `Parameters`. Может необходимо установить какие то пакеты расширения? Есть только `Add` и `AddRange`

Comment: Ясно это не SQLcommand класс. Щя напильником подправим

Comment: Add метод есть надеюсь? я чуток подправил код

Comment: да , метод add есть

Comment: @gregor как успехи?

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось